# How much does equipment cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, pricing

How can I find out what amount of money gear costs?
For example, "Hide Armor costs 50 gp." How much would Potions and Tools cost?

Comment: To explain why you're getting down voted, it's probably because this question is easily answered by even a cursory glance at the rules. People here expect posters to show at least a basic attempt at finding the answer themselves before coming here.

Comment: To give you an idea on what's behind Derek's point, please see the this [meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270/22566)

Answer (score 12):

All the usual equipment costs are in the [Dungeons and Dragons Player's Handbook](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_playershandbook) in Chapter 5: Equipment.  They can also be found online as part of the [5e System Resource Document](http://www.5esrd.com/equipment/).

If you don't have a copy of the Player's Handbook, you will probably be pretty lost in the game, as it will answer hundreds of basic questions of this sort for you.  It's available at various friendly retailers (physical or online).

Potions beyond the potion of healing are considered magical treasure and the prices are in the Dungeon Master's Guide, but your DM may control their availability and price.  (In fact, you should ask them about normal equipment too, just because it's in the PHB at a certain price doesn't mean that necessarily holds in their game world.)